# make api file inside theme folder in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am writing an api for my wordpress blog. I have a file inside my wp-themes / theme-name called api.php
I want to call that api  from external url and have it respond with json data. But i want to do it without using header / footer them files.

Right now it works with header / footer included, but that isn't ideal api response. so what files should i include in it, so that I can use all wordpress functions, without the need to include the header and footer theme files.

Comment: Can you provide a bit code here, and the api that you are using

Answer (score 0):

You need to require **wp-load.php** and call **wp()**